# Environment Variables with $ Character

Tags: shell, environment-variables, quoting

I'm using a MacOS. I tried to enter this environment variable inside my `.bash_profile`:

`export CLOUD_PASSWORD=Pass4Aa$ditya`

But when I do `source .bash_profile` and try `echo $CLOUD_PASSWORD`, I get this as output: 
`Pass4Aa`

Anything after that $ sign is getting ignored. Even when I tried adding quotes like:
`export CLOUD_PASSWORD="Pass4Aa$ditya"`

and did `source` later, it is still showing the same as before. How do I create environment variables with Special Characters like $ and @ present in the value?

Comment: See [How to use a special character as a normal one?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Comment: sample: export foo=$'\x41\x42\x43\x44'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$ export CLOUD_PASSWORD='Pass4Aa$ditya'
$ printf '%s\n' "$CLOUD_PASSWORD"

Pass4Aa$ditya

$ export CLOUD_PASSWORD="Pass4Aa\$ditya"
$ printf '%s\n' "$CLOUD_PASSWORD"

Pass4Aa$ditya
```

single quotes or escaping with backslashes :)

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes to assign value to variable in `.bash_profile` file.

Add following line in `.bash_profile` -

```
export CLOUD_PASSWORD='Pass4Aa$ditya'
```

Verify the changes -

```
$ source .bash_profile
$ printf '%s\n' "$CLOUD_PASSWORD"
Pass4Aa$ditya
```